# Is there a function to "evaluate" a range of numbers in a string?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a "legend" that describes the category a number can go into. I'd like to sort numbers into these categories using some kind of `case_when` approach.  Is there a way to "evaluate" the range of numbers from these strings so that I can sort the numbers accordingly?

```
tribble(~n_treatment_category, ~level,
        "< 25", 1,
        "26 - 34", 2,
        "35 - 47", 3,
        "48 - 77", 4,
        "> 78 ", 5)
```

Comment: I think the answer on that question depends a lot on the format that the groups will be given. Do they exactly follow your template: the first category is of the form "< x", the last "> y", the others "a - b" and they are ordered? Or could this vary?

Comment: I think they exactly follow this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `treatcat` is the input vector of category range strings.  Note that there is an error in the question since for the ranges to be correct the inequalities should be <= and >= .  Below we have treated < and > as if they were <= and >=.

Now read the numbers in and use the indicated `cut` command.  Use `labels = FALSE` in the `cut` command if you want integer categories instead or omit labels to get labels of the form (---, ---] .

Here we categorize the numbers 1:100 so replace that with whatever you want to categorize.

```
treatcat <- c("< 25", "26 - 34", "35 - 47", "48 - 77", "> 78 ") # test input

r <- na.omit(read.table(text = gsub("[<>-]", "", treatcat), fill = NA, header = FALSE))
cc <- cut(1:100, c(-Inf, r$V1 - 1, r$V2[nrow(r)], Inf), labels = treatcat)
cc
```

giving:

```
  [1] < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25   
 [10] < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25   
 [19] < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    < 25    26 - 34 26 - 34
 [28] 26 - 34 26 - 34 26 - 34 26 - 34 26 - 34 26 - 34 26 - 34 35 - 47 35 - 47
 [37] 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47 35 - 47
 [46] 35 - 47 35 - 47 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77
 [55] 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77
 [64] 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77
 [73] 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 48 - 77 > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78   
 [82] > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78   
 [91] > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78    > 78   
[100] > 78   
Levels: < 25 26 - 34 35 - 47 48 - 77 > 78
```

### Check answer

We can verify that the above is correct like this:

```
split(1:100, cc)
```

giving:

```
$`< 25`
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

$`26 - 34`
[1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34

$`35 - 47`
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47

$`48 - 77`
 [1] 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
[26] 73 74 75 76 77

$`> 78 `
 [1]  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
[20]  97  98  99 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some string manipulation to tease out the boundaries and then use `findInterval`:

```
range <- gsub("[<> ]", "", dat$n_treatment_category)
range <- gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", range)
range <- sort(as.numeric(range))[-1] # don't need lowest number

set.seed(1)
numbers <- runif(10, 0, 100)

numbers
#> [1] 26.551 37.212 57.285 90.821 20.168 89.839 94.468 66.080 62.911  6.179

findInterval(numbers, c(0, range, Inf), right = FALSE)
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 1 5 5 4 4 1
```